# Manage iAd banner's touch while using iAdAdditions category

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, iad, banner

iOS 7 bring the iAdAdditions category to UIViewController.
With it managing a banner is a matter of one line of code:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

But I wonder how to detect user touching the iAd banner. My need is to pause game behaviors (music, animations, timers...) while iAd is displayed full screen.

I have tried the following code:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self isPresentingFullScreenAd]) {
        // view will disappear because of user action on iAd banner
    }
    else {
        // view will disappear for any other reasons
    }
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self isPresentingFullScreenAd]) {
        // view will appear because full screen iAd — caused by previous user action on iAd banner — is dismissed
    }
    else {
        // view will appear for other reasons
    }
}
```

I have done some testings showing everything is OK. But I wonder if it's the correct way to implement it!

### UPDATE

This is the solution I use in the production version of the application and everything is fine: no problems has showned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these specific delegates in your view controller, here's code ripped straight from my game where I toggle the audio/music off when a banner is clicked.

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner
               willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    [[CPAudioManager sharedInstance] toggleOnOffDependingOnSettings];

    return YES;
}

-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [[CPAudioManager sharedInstance] toggleOnOffDependingOnSettings];
}
```

For full screen *interstitials* the code is roughly the same, but you don't get such nice delegates.

You know when you are showing a full screen ad when you call `requestInterstitialAdPresentation` and it returns `YES`, e.g.

```
if( [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation]==YES ) {...}
```

You should pause your views, toggle your music off, and kill your banner view (probably).

Then, you know when the user has closed the interstitial in `ViewDidAppear`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if( self.isPresentingFullScreenAd )
    {
        // we are about to stop presenting full screen ads
        // unpause view
        // enable banner ads
        // turn music back on if it was playing before
    }
    else
    {
        // we are presenting the normal view or the full screen ad
    }
}
```

Comment: I used _self.isPresentingFullScreenAd_ in booth _viewWillDisappear_ and _viewWillAppear_ to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: That's great if that worked for you! I've discovered you can't trust isPresentingFullScreenAd except for when views are transitioning. E.g. if you randomly call it after you know ads aren't showing - it will still be YES. I've reported that to apple with sample code too.

Comment: Is there a question related to this point opened on StackOverflow?